# How can I pass command line arguments contained in a file and retain the name of that file?

Tags: python, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, argparse

I have a script that consumes command line arguments and I would like to implement two argument-passing schemes, namely:

- Typing the arguments out at the command line.
- Storing the argument list in a file, and passing the name of this file to the program via the command line.

To that end I am passing the argument `fromfile_prefix_chars` to the `ArgumentParser` constructor.

#### script.py

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
parser = ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
parser.add_argument('filename', nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs='?', default=1)
parser.add_argument('--bar', nargs='?', default=1)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

#### args.txt

```
--foo
2
--bar
2
```

#### Sample use cases

```
$ python script.py --foo 3
Namespace(bar=1, filename=None, foo='3')
$ python script.py @args.txt --foo 3
Namespace(bar='2', filename=None, foo='3')
```

I was expecting that `args.filename` would retain the name of the file, but surprinsingly enough it has the value `None` instead. I am aware that I could get the file name from `sys.argv` through a bit of processing. Is there a cleaner way (ideally an `argparse`-based approach) to elicit the name of the arguments file?

Comment: What is up with the @args.txt why not args.txt, filename stores args.txt if you remove the @

Comment: @G.LC indeed it does, but then the arguments don't get passed to the program.

Comment: @101arrowz Ok wasn't aware of that

Comment: So instead of using a fromfile prefix and all, could you just have the filename be a positional argument, then read the variables from that file using readlines()?  I mean, sure, it'd be a bit workaroundish, and not the most Pythonic way, but it'd hold until another solution is found.  If this way is acceptable, I could write a little answer to give a working example.

Comment: Wow.  didn’t know @filename capability at all.  but, could you call parse twice?  one with @, once without?   You can provide your own argument list from a modded sys.argv.  Then adjust one of the Namespaces from the other, it’s fairly permissive.

Comment: @MegaEmailman That was my plan B :) 
Hopefully someone will come up with a smarter solution...

Comment: Your `args.txt` does not give any value for `filename` nor does your command line. Why do you expect it to have a value different from `None`? The `fromfile_prefix_chars` does a very specific thing: when it sees `@something` replaces `@something` with the arguments parsed from the file, period. It is **designed** to be invisible to the arguments since it's something handled before the actual command line parsing.

Comment: From the documentation "arguments that start with any of the specified characters will be treated as files, and will be **replaced** by the arguments they contain."

Comment: @Bakuriu has a point. I don't know why you need access to the filename, but my answer offers a possibly (if unpythonic) solution. MAKE SURE you actually need the filename, because doing what I suggest is specifically what the `fromfile_prefix_chars` argument was designed to prevent.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.convert_arg_line_to_args documents how reading the prefix file can be be customized.  This function is called near the start of parsing by the `_read_args_from_files(self, arg_strings)` method.  Look at the `argparse.py` code file for full context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my testing, using `fromfile_prefix_chars` means that argparse will not actually pass the argument to your program. Instead, `argparse` sees the `@args.txt`, intercepts it, reads from it, and passes the arguments without `@args.txt` to your program. This is presumably because most people don't really need the filename, just need the arguments within, so `argparse` saves you the trouble of creating another argument to store something you don't need.

Unfortunately, all of the arguments are stored as local variables in `argparse.py`, so we cannot access them. I suppose that you could override some of argparse's functions. Keep in mind that this is a horrible, disgusting, hacky solution and I feel that parsing `sys.argv` is 100% better.

```py
from argparse import ArgumentParser

# Most of the following is copied from argparse.py
def customReadArgs(self, arg_strings):
    # expand arguments referencing files
    new_arg_strings = []
    for arg_string in arg_strings:

        # for regular arguments, just add them back into the list
        if not arg_string or arg_string[0] not in self.fromfile_prefix_chars:
            new_arg_strings.append(arg_string)

        # replace arguments referencing files with the file content
        else:
            try:
                fn = arg_string[1:]
                with open(fn) as args_file:

                    # What was changed: before was []
                    arg_strings = [fn]

                    for arg_line in args_file.read().splitlines():
                        for arg in self.convert_arg_line_to_args(arg_line):
                            arg_strings.append(arg)
                    arg_strings = self._read_args_from_files(arg_strings)
                    new_arg_strings.extend(arg_strings)
            except OSError:
                err = _sys.exc_info()[1]
                self.error(str(err))

    # return the modified argument list
    return new_arg_strings
ArgumentParser._read_args_from_files = customReadArgs
parser = ArgumentParser(fromfile_prefix_chars='@')
parser.add_argument('filename', nargs='?')
parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs='?', default=1)
parser.add_argument('--bar', nargs='?', default=1)
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

Comment: Indeed, your solution is hacky... but it works fine! I have finally subclassed `argparse.ArgumentParser` and overriden the `_read_args_from_files` method in the child class `MyArgumentParser`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `script.py`, plus the file.  I have added the file name to the file itself.

#### args.txt

```
args.txt
--foo
2
--bar
2
```

testing:

```
1803:~/mypy$ python3 stack56811067.py --foo 3
Namespace(bar=1, filename=None, foo='3')
1553:~/mypy$ python3 stack56811067.py @args.txt --foo 3
Namespace(bar='2', filename='args.txt', foo='3')
```

Comment: Neat and clever! The problem with your approach though is that if the file name changes you need to remember to change the first line accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, here's a quick and dirty solution I came up with. It basically consists in creating a copy of `parser` and set its `from_file_prefix_chars` attribute to `None`:

```
import copy

parser_dupe = copy.copy(parser)
parser_dupe.fromfile_prefix_chars = None
args_raw = parser_dupe.parse_args()
if args_raw.filename:
    args.filename = args_raw.filename[1:]
```